# I'm getting a NameError from using the event function from pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making an electrical circuit simulator that's graphically based using Pygame and while using "event.type", I get a 'NameError'

This is for a school project. Here's some code:

```
#Drawing Rectangles (later used as buttons)
batteryBtn = pygame.draw.rect(display, red, (0,0,100,50))
bulbBtn = pygame.draw.rect(display, green, (100,0,100,50))
resistorBtn = pygame.draw.rect(display, blue, (200,0,100,50))

#Initialising the images
img1 = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Amine\Pictures\Battery.jpg')
img2 = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Amine\Pictures\bulbOn.jpg')
img3 = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Amine\Pictures\bulbOff.jpg')
img4 = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Amine\Pictures\Resistor.jpg')

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if event.button == 1:
        if batteryBtn.collidepoint(pos):
            display.blit(img1, (0, 100))
```

I was expecting the program to let me click on the red rectangle and the image would pop up as a result, but I got the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amine\Desktop\ComputerScienceProject\Computer Science proj Pygame.py", line 25, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you defining `event`?

Comment: You are missing `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Comment: Also, you should have a minimal reproducible example. In other words, I should be able to copy your code and run it without making any changes, and get the same error you did. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

What your code is missing is something called the event loop which defines the event variable (what is causing your error). Its syntax is this:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    #all of your events and such, in your case if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
```

You can read up on all the events in the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) or [here](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/05/Pygame-modules-for-interactive-programs) (a helpful little guide)

other ways you can solve this is by using this

```py
pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
```

which checks if the left mouse button is down. (read about it [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html)).

or by putting right before you check if mouse is clicked

```py
event = pygame.event.wait()
```

which functions the same way as the event loop except that it pauses the program if no events are occuring.